# How to make a div full sized in CSS?

Tags: html, css, margin

I couldn't figure out how to properly give a margin to my weather-form-div since when I try to set a margin, the div of class App is moved accordingly. I want the size of the div of class App to be fixed.

```
*{
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  background-image: url('https://wallpapercave.com/wp/wp2733241.png');
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  min-height: 100vh;
  
}

.App{
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
}

.weather-form-div{
  border: 4px solid red;
  width: 372px;
  margin: 50px auto;
}

.weather-form{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

Comment: Try `height: calc(100vh - 50px);` same with `width`

Comment: It works thank you. By the way, using display flex also resolve this question but I don't know the reason.

Answer (score 0):

try using flex property as the  flex container expands items to fill available free space or shrinks them to prevent overflow